# What causes a Responder status in a SAML response

Tags: php, saml, saml-2.0, onelogin

I am having quite a time setting up SAML integration with a client using our platform. We're using [OneLogin's php sdk](https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml) on our end to act as a service provider. Not sure what they're using as an identity provider or if it is something custom.

It seems no matter what we do, the AuthN Response we receive from them has the status: `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder`

As I read it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh269642.aspx), all that means is that there was an issue (we don't know what) on their side. Sort of the equivalent of a 500 status in php.

The guy I'm working with on their end is **sure** that this is an issue of a configuration mismatch. Either that they're not providing the right claims, or not signing the part we're asking them to sign, etc.

But if that were the case... wouldn't they still send us a response with a success status? And maybe we'd get an error on *our* side if they didn't sign it right. But I wouldn't expect to receive the 'Responder' status from them.

Can anyone either confirm that I'm making the right assumption or set me straight it I'm wrong?

Comment: Old now and probably not the case here (so just a comment), but one reason you can get this response is if the IdP detects a redirect loop. The IdP will issue this in order to break the cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are correct. Those two errors would not be noticed before the message reaches your side. It something else and it should not be that impossible to find looking at the logs at their side.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, In most cases, the issue occurs due to mismatching of the signature algorithms. In our case, we are using Spring SAML and as Spring SAML uses SHA-1 by default and IDP is using the different signature algorithm (SHA-256). Therefore, we are also receiving the same response `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder, status message is null` due to mismatch of algorithms and same may occur with other library which you are using to integrate with IDP.

Following is the exception trace with spring SAML security.

```
Caused by: org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: Response has invalid status code urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder, status message is null
org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(SAMLAuthenticationProvider.java:82)
```